# Can I declare the same variable twice in different for loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, var, declare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

I have a JavaScript function for HTML select options for days:

```
// Show and hide days according to the selected year and month.
function show_and_hide_days(fp_form) {
    var select_year= $(fp_form).find("select.value_year");
    var select_month= $(fp_form).find("select.value_month");
    var select_day= $(fp_form).find("select.value_day");
    var selected_year= $.parse_int($(select_year).val());
    var selected_month= $.parse_int($(select_month).val());
    var selected_day= $.parse_int($(select_day).val());
    var days_in_month= new Date(selected_year, selected_month, 0).getDate();
    // If the number of days in the selected month is less than 28, change it to 31.
    if (!(days_in_month >= 28))
    {
        days_in_month= 31;
    }
    // If the selected day is bigger than the number of days in the selected month, reduce it to the last day in this month.
    if (selected_day > days_in_month)
    {
        selected_day= days_in_month;
    }
    // Remove days 29 to 31, then append days 29 to days_in_month.
    for (var day= 31; day >= 29; day--)
    {
        $(select_day).find("option[value='" + day + "']").remove();
    }
    for (var day= 29; day <= days_in_month; day++)
    {
        $(select_day).append("<option value=\"" + day + "\">" + day + "</option>");
    }
    // Restore the selected day.
    $(select_day).val(selected_day);
}
```

My question is - can I declare "var day" twice in two different for loops and what is the scope of this variable? Is it legal and what happens if I declare the same variable twice in the same function? (inside for loops or outside for loops)? For example, what happens if I declare one of the variables again with "var"?

If I don't use "var" at all before variable day in for loops, what will happen?

Thanks,
Uri.

P.S. $.parse_int is a jQuery plugin which calls parseInt with radix 10 if not specified.

Comment: You can test for yourself. Just try and see what happens!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Any use of `var foo` in a function will scope `foo` to that function. It doesn't matter where in the function this takes place as `var` declarations are hoisted.

Additional uses of `var foo` in the same function are syntactically legal but will have no effect as the variable is already scoped to that function.

Since it has no effect, there is a school of thought that recommends against it (and in favour of a single `var` function at the very top of a function to perform all the scoping) to avoid implying that there is significance to it (to maintainers who are not entirely comfortable with this feature of JavaScript). [JSLint](http://jslint.com) will alert you to this usage.

Answer (score 5):

No you shouldn't. Variables declared using `var` have function scope, not block scope!

Redeclaring a variable using `var` might suggest that the variable is local to the loop/block when it isn't.

You could, however use `let` to declare the variable, to ensure it is block-scoped.

```js
for (let x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
   console.log(x)
}
    
for (let w = 65, x = String.fromCharCode(w); w <= 67; w++, x = String.fromCharCode(w)){
    console.log(x)
}

console.log(typeof x) // undefined
```